# VBA - Execution escapes one sub and runs another sub partly

Tags: vba

I have two Sub routines, that do NOT call each other.
But when I run the first one and it loops through the for each loop in it,
it suddenly runs the first two lines of the next method which stands right beneath the first one. Here is a code example of my problem, unfortunately I cannot show you the real code since the company I am working for does not allow it:

```
    Public Sub PrintA()
        Dim i as Variant
        for each i in Products
            '--- Here comes a lot of code, but definitely no call of PrintB!
        next i
    End Sub

    Public Sub PrintB()
        Dim Hubs(2) As String
        Hubs(0) = "HUB1"
        Hubs(1) = "HUB2"
        '--- a lot of more code following but only the above three lines are
        '--- being executed for whatever reason

    End Sub
```

After named 3 lines of code are executed, it continues to loop through the for each loop in the first method and I simply don't understand what's happening...

Comment: It can't just call 2 lines - it either calls the entire sub or nothing from it assuming there isnt any goto etc

Comment: When you step through, when exactly does it jump to PrintB? Do you have a `main` sub that might call it? Can you explain what `Products` is?

Comment: `Products` is a Collection of Product Objects which I loop through to print them in an excel sheet.

Comment: Does the products collection use anything from PrintB? Any 'hubs'. What line does it jump form? Have you stepped through? I can't fathom ANY way that VBA would just run a few lines of code and then just give up, let alone 2 lines that aren't called.

Comment: There is nothing in what you posted that can help us diagnose your issue.  Unless you can reproduce it with non-proprietary code that you can share, you're going to have to step through it line by line.

Comment: Do you have a worksheet change event that's being fired off?  Also, perhaps you have an On Error Resume Next statement that's masking the issue.

Comment: Yes, RossC, I have stepped through. It runs the complete code in the for each loop inside the PrintA method and then, right before the `next i` Statement is executed, it jumps to the `Public Sub PrintB()` and runs until after the `Hubs(1) = "HUB2"` statement.

Then - back in the `PrintA` Sub it continues with the for each loop.

Comment: Is there code Worksheet Change (or open etc) Event? Is there an on Error Resume Next somewhere? **Something** has to be firing off an event. There's not enough information here to diagnose this IMHO.

Comment: There is definitely no Event fireing. And the only code where I use the On Error Flag is while Scanning Data.
But this problem only occurs in the Output part of the macro so I don't think that that actually causes the problem

Comment: **Something** must be calling this, are you sure there's no events anywhere behind the scenes? In 'this workbook' or behind any of the sheets. Any 'OnOpen' 'OnChange' type things? It can't just decide itself to jump subs and then exit out again. Are the hubs dependent on anything, does the collection reference anything that could cause this? I'm totally at a loss now, I don't think I can do anything more without more code or details. Are there userforms in the app that may run code on close or at other events?

Comment: It cannot happen and thus most probably it does not happen. You will have to do more investigation yourself. Try to copy problematic part to another project/document and see, if the problem persists.

Comment: There are no such events.
I, myself, am completely clueless. I have never had a comparable problem before in ANY language and I know it SHOULD be impossible.

I suppose it just is a bug in the Debugger, since I cannot find any other reason for this behaveiour. And since it only fills up the 2 fields in the array it also is not that much of a problem but still hella confusing ...

If there is any event triggering it, I cannot see it. I definitely did not program one to fire so I don't know.

Comment: Is it Excel? Which version? Did you check the Call Stack Window when the problem occurs? Do the values Hubs(0) and Hubs(1) really get initialized?

Comment: I just wanted to check the Call Stack Window but apparently it was a bug since Excel just crashed ...
Now that I restarted it, the problem no longer occurs... 
I am seriously confused now but at least it works now -.-

Comment: OK, good for you - so the accepted answer was: Turn it off and on again...:)

Comment: Apparently xD
Now I think I should have tried that first. I blame it on the IT in my company or even better - I blame Microsoft :P

Thanks everyone for the help!!

Comment: Ha! That's a bit annoying in a way but I'm glad it worked. I watched a friend with a PHd in comp sci, spend 3 hours fixing a soundcard issue  with NO success until his younger brother fell into the room drunk and plugged all the wires out and in again: worked immediately. I think sometimes it's easy to look for a complex solution. I guess "have you tried turning it on and off again" is actually good advice!!

Comment: I have found that copying the module contents into a new module (omitting the trailing white space) alleviates strangeness such as code interrupts where there are no code breaks present, and random crashing.  You could have had underlying artifacts (or whatever you want to call them).

Comment: @n8 That actually sounds like an explanation I can at least accept xD
Definitely better than "Random Awesomenes".

Comment: @RossC Yeah I know that feeling. The more you know about what you do the more you tend to think more complicated while others with less experience often have "stupid" ideas which then oftenly work.
I suppose it's a common phenomenon known to everyone :P
But thanks again for all the help :)